# Authendication data Store in android

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, android-authenticator

I Know If the User have to Store UserName and Password then we can create Class and **store the UserName** and **Password** in Class. At get the data using `SharedPreferences` for that class.But That class `store the data upto` we `can not close the Application`. If we close the Application then data will be destroyed.

**My Question is :**

I Want to Store Data in Application if the User close the application or Restart the Mobile device. But the data are Store in the Class. How to perform this task. I am new to android. Please Help me.

Comment: Who said data is destroyed ? if you're using `SharedPreferences` then it's stay there even if your app closed.

Comment: If I Shut down Mobile Device then. ?

Comment: Still there budy check it out. i am damn 100% sure.

Comment: Ask by your self. I don't have time.

Comment: can you post the code you are using to store data.

Comment: @Ankur1994a  I want to also Know the Mechnism to perform this.

Comment: Try this to store username and password.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example
its sure no data is loss in SharesPreferances

Comment: @Ankur1994a I Know this way But the Data will Destroy if I close the Mobile device.

Comment: can i know how you are using SharedPreferences to save the data, how you are retrieving that.

Comment: @Ankur1994a Simple SharedPreferences with get and set

Comment: i am asking about your code can you post it.

Comment: @Ankur1994a I edited the question ?

Comment: why are you passing null in this.getSharedPreferences("Login",null); when getting values. use 0 instead of it. 0 is use for getting SharedPreferances in private mode.

Comment: Ok I keep in mind But Do you have any Idea About My Question any Mechnism for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are new to Android. So, you should go through this link. You got these many Storage options in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In your case, You can go with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Your data will be stored in key-value pair. And also, it is persistent storage.